# Apache Rewrite of HTTPS on another specific port with hidden subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, tomcat6

I have a Tomcat behind an Apache server and I would like to use the https request to be rewritten to the Tomcat on port 9001 with a hidden subfolder /test.

**hosts** entry:

```
127.0.0.1 local.domain.com
```

I tried the following in different configurations in the **httpd.conf** but with no success:

**VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^(www\.)?local\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^subdir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://local.domain.com:9001/subdir/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: AFAIK there is only a HTTP_HOST server variable and no HTTPS_HOST (and https would never be present in the plain HTTP virtual host running on port 80)...